# Creating condtional shortcode echo - WP/Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, hook-woocommerce

I've created a bunch of shortcodes that are either used within posts or echo'd into product pages using wordpress hooks.

I'm trying to create a conditional function so it echos a specific shortcode dependent on the product category. It would need to echo into the 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary'.

This is the draft so far, can someone give some advice on how to complete this please?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'add_warranty_notice', 15 );

function add_warranty_notice() {

if ( is_product_category( 'xx-slug' ) ) {
echo do_shortcode("[xx-product-notice]");
} elseif ( is_product_category( 'xy-slug' ) ) {
echo do_shortcode("[xy-product-notice]");
}

}
```

Comment: Explain what exactly still needs completion? How far did what you have shown get you, what exactly is still missing?

Comment: So the idea is to echo a shortcode into the page in the 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' based on the product category.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'add_warranty_notice', 15 );

function add_warranty_notice() {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    $nterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag'  );
    foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {
        $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
        $product_cat_name = $term->name;
        break;
    }

    if ( $product_cat_name == 'parent_one' ) {
        echo do_shortcode("[xx-product-notice]");
    } elseif ( $product_cat_name == 'parent_two' ) {
        echo do_shortcode("[xy-product-notice]");
    }else{

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I've tried both the category slug & name as options but it still doesnt render.

Comment: Tested It’s working slug based. What are you tried?